# habilitar o deshabilitar button segun select option

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, select

Teniendo el siguiente codigo:

```
<?php
                    $conexion->set_charset("utf8");
                    $conexion->query("SET @index:=0");
                    $consulta = "SELECT

                    @index:=@index+1 AS 'index',
                    ocd.id_dsc,
                    ocd.cantidad,
                    um.nombre AS um,
                    prod.nombre AS insumo,
                    pv.nombre AS proveedor,
                    cc.nombre AS c_costo,
                    ocd.valor,
                    ocd.iva,
                    ocd.total,
                    us.nombre AS creado_por,
                    oc.fecha_solicitud,
                    oc.fecha_oc

                    FROM orden_compra_det ocd

                    INNER JOIN orden_compra oc ON oc.id_sol = ocd.id_sol
                    INNER JOIN proveedores pv ON pv.id = oc.prov
                    INNER JOIN prod_bodega_test prod ON prod.id = ocd.prod
                    INNER JOIN usuarios us ON us.id = oc.creada_por
                    INNER JOIN unidad_medida um ON um.id = ocd.um
                    INNER JOIN centro_costo cc ON cc.id = oc.c_costo

                    WHERE ocd.id_cl = '$id_cl' AND oc.id_sol = '$id_sol' AND oc.empresa = '$emp' ";
                    $resultado = $conexion->query($consulta);
                    if ($resultado->num_rows > 0){
                      while ($row = $resultado->fetch_array()) {
                        $id_prueba[] = $row['id_dsc'];

                     ?>
                  <tr>
                    <td style="width:50px"><?=$id_sol?></td>
                    <td style="width:50px"><?=$row['index']; ?></td>
                    <td><?=strtoupper($row['insumo'])?></td>
                    <td style="width:50px"><?=$row['cantidad']; ?></td>
                    <td style="width:80px">$<?=number_format($row['valor'], 0, ',', '.')?></td>
                    <td style="width:80px">$<?=number_format($row['iva'], 0, ',', '.')?></td>
                    <td style="width:80px">$<?=number_format($row['total'], 0, ',', '.')?></td>
                    <td style="width:220px">
                      <select class='form-control select2' name='opcion[]' id='opcion' required>
                        <option value=''>SELECCIONE OPCION</option>
                        <option value='1' selected='selected'>APROBAR</option>
                        <option value='2'>APROBAR CON REPAROS</option>
                        <option value='3'>RECHAZAR</option>
                        <option value='4'>PENDIENTE</option>
                      </select>
                    </td>
                    <td><input type="button" id="btn" value="BOTON" disabled data-toggle="modal" data-target="#finaliza" data-book-id="<?=$row['id_dsc']?>"></input></td>
                    <td style="width:380px"><input type="text" name="obs_ind[]" style="width:380px; text-align: center" autocomplete="off"></td>
                  </tr>
                  <?php } } ?>

              </tbody>
            </table>
```

y la funcion:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 $("#opcion").change( function() {
  if($(this).val() === "2") {
   $("#btn").prop("disabled", false);
  }else{
   $("#btn").prop("disabled", true);
  }
 });
});
```

estoy tratando que cada vez que se seleccione la opción APROBAR CON REPAROS (value=2), se active el button y permanezca deshabilitado mientras no se seleccione esta opcion en los demas .
Actualmente, el código solo funciona para el primer registro y no para los demás que se encuentren en la tabla.
Alguna sugerencia o ayuda?
Desde ya muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tenes un select con un id que deberia ser unico dentro de un bucle, podes usar el id del registro para identificarlo y tenerlo como elemento unico. Pasa lo mismo con los botones, si queres cambiar con el cambio de un select el boton de esa linea deberias hacerlo asi.

```
<tr>
    <td style="width:50px"><?=$id_sol?></td>
    <td style="width:50px"><?=$row['index']; ?></td>
    <td><?=strtoupper($row['insumo'])?></td>
    <td style="width:50px"><?=$row['cantidad']; ?></td>
    <td style="width:80px">$<?=number_format($row['valor'], 0, ',', '.')?></td>
    <td style="width:80px">$<?=number_format($row['iva'], 0, ',', '.')?></td>
    <td style="width:80px">$<?=number_format($row['total'], 0, ',', '.')?></td>
    <td style="width:220px">
        <select class='form-control select2' name='opcion[]' id='opcion<?=$id_sol?>' onchange="validar(<?=$id_sol?>)" required>
           <option value=''>SELECCIONE OPCION</option>
           <option value='1' selected='selected'>APROBAR</option>
           <option value='2'>APROBAR CON REPAROS</option>
           <option value='3'>RECHAZAR</option>
           <option value='4'>PENDIENTE</option>
        </select>
     </td>
     <td><input type="button" id="btn<?=$id_sol?>" value="BOTON" disabled data-toggle="modal" data-target="#finaliza" data-book-id="<?=$row['id_dsc']?>"></input></td>
<script>
    function validar(id){
       var estado = true;
       if($("#opcion"+id).val() == '2'){
          estado = false;
       }
       $("#btn"+id).prop("disabled", estado); 
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Estimado, muchas gracias por responder. Cuando leia la explicación, me quedo claro cual era el problema e igual desde ahora saber que se pueden agregar identificadores a botones en este tipo de usabilidad. Agradezco tu tiempo y tu ayuda. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Si tienes mas de uno puedes recorrerlos todos para segurarte cada vez que cambie que este no este en otro select, solo tendrias que cambiar la busqueda de id por class

```
var opcion = document.getElementsByClassName("opcion");
var boton = document.getElementById("btn");
for(i = 0; i < opcion.length ; i++){
  if(opcion[i].value === "2"){
    btn.setAttribute("disabled", "false");
  }else{
    btn.setAttribute("disabled", "true");
  }
}
```